# What is meant by without exposing the 'internal structure'? (iterator)

Tags: java, oop, collections, iterator

One of the key attributes of an iterator is that

> The iterator pattern allow us to:
>
> - access contents of a collection without exposing its internal structure.

What exactly is meant by that, what is the internal structure?

Comment: It means you can go through each item without knowing how they got there, how they are removed, how they are stored, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Every data structure is implemented differently. Some structures might use a linked design, some might be backed by a single array, or there could be some mix of the two. Imagine if every time you wanted to use a different `List` implementation, you needed to learn about how it works just to use it.

The Iterator interface (along with other Interfaces) provide(s) a consistent set of methods that allow you to use an iterable, even if you have no idea how it's implemented "under the hood".

Answer (score 1):

The internal structure is the private member[s] that hold the contents of the collection.

For example, in `ArrayList`, the internal structure is a backing array holding the elements of the `List`:

```
transient Object[] elementData;
```

The `Iterator` returned by `ArrayList`'s `iterator()` gives you access to the elements of the `ArrayList` without giving you access to the backing array, which means you cannot mutate the backing array directly.

For `HashSet`, the internal structure is a `HashMap` that holds the elements of the `Set`:

```
private transient HashMap<E,Object> map;
```

Again, the iterator gives you access to the elements of the `Set` without giving you access to that `HashMap`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: The iterator provides a remove method. So, I think the phrase "cannot mutate" can be reworded

Comment: @user7 please note the rest of the sentence - "cannot mutate the backing array **directly**"

Answer (score 1):

In this context *internal structure* means the list of member functions of the collection class or interface. But thinking further, as the member function list roughly makes up the class / interface, *internal structure* means the class / interface of the collection. And this statement is wide and can mean the sort of collection like array, bag, queue...

An iterator is an adapter often with a different interface than the collections it operates on. So using an iterator not only enables us to hide the collection's class declaration (which defines the collection's internal structure) but also enables us to hide the collection's public interface (which might be separate and smaller than the whole collection's class declaration). And this public interface is not internal structure. So your original statement *without exposing its internal structure* is ok but not completely comprehensive.

An iterator saves us not only from exposing internal structure but also from exposing the public interface of the collection. And this gives more value to the concept of iterator in context of code separation.

Answer (score 1):

As a simple example, a `TreeMap` can be iterated to learn all members of the map.  When using an iterator, I don't have to care whether the tree underlying the map is a binary tree, a trie, a b-tree, a red-black tree, etc.  As a user I don't want to have to know how it maintains its internal links to read its data. I don't want to have to know anything about its implementation.  Software that seeks *maintainability* should reduce the amount a user needs to know about its implementation.

"Structure" in this sense is used in the same manner as in "data structure"...a way of organizing data in memory to permit efficient lookup, insertion, deletion, or other operations.  An iterator hides the details of the organization scheme used to make the operations efficient, by providing a simple way to get the data, item by item, just by calling `next()`.